# FlatList not showing up

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am following a tutorial video for React Native. Everything is working well besides the FlatList, I am unable to make it show up on the simulator. I am using expo, while this tutorial is done using bare. Maybe that is causing the issue, but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Here is a link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPu1ax1Fga0&t=2179s

Link to the github for the source code: https://github.com/mattfrances/FoodAppUI

This is the code for the FlatList

```
        <View style={styles.categoriesWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.categoriesTitle}>Categories</Text>
          <View style={styles.categoriesListWrapper}>
            <FlatList
              data={categoriesData}
              renderItem={renderCategoryItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              horizontal={true}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
```

Here is the renderCategoryItem code:

```
const renderCategoryItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
          <View
            style={[
              styles.categoryItemWrapper,
              {
                backgroundColor: item.selected ? colors.primary : colors.white,
                marginLeft: item.id == 1 ? 20 : 0,
              },
            ]}>
            <Image source={item.image} style={styles.categoryItemImage} />
            <Text style={styles.categoryItemTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
            <View
              style={[
                styles.categorySelectWrapper,
                {
                  backgroundColor: item.selected ? colors.white : colors.secondary,
                },
              ]}>
              <Feather
                name="chevron-right"
                size={8}
                style={styles.categorySelectIcon}
                color={item.selected ? colors.black : colors.white}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!